# Personalizar ActionBar o ToolBar

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, toolbar, actionbar

Hola amigos que todo lo saben.
Estoy introduciendome en Android con Java y una cosa me tiene empantanado.

Estoy creando un menu de navegación y tambien le estoy metiendo fragments.
Al momento de presionar un boton, quisiera que el titulo del ActionBar o ToolBar  como lo llaman en internet, cambie de nombre según el boton que se presionó.

[![Imagen de Referencia de la Interfaz en la parte de abajo][1]][1]

Hasta aquí va quedando el código Java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =  findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, new SecondFragment()).commit();
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_security);

    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.firstFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new FirstFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.secondFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new SecondFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.thirdFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new ThirdFragment();
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBmAY.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar el titulo del `ActionBar`, puedes poner este còdigo en cada Fragment:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hola FirstFragment");
```

haciendo referencia a la `Activity` que carga el Fragment se puede cambiar el titulo.

Para realizarlo desde el botòn lo realizarìas de esta forma:

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.firstFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new FirstFragment();
                      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hola FirstFragment");
                    break;
                case R.id.secondFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new SecondFragment();
                      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hola SecondFragment");

                    break;
                case R.id.thirdFragment:
                    selectedFragment = new ThirdFragment();
                      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hola thirdFragment");

                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, directo al clavo.  Estaba viendo que lo hacian en kotlin y no sabía como pasarlo a Java.
Gracias!